# Como substituir texto de coluna no SQL Server (tsql)?

Tags: sql-server, tsql

Tenho uma coluna de texto no SQL Server 2008 R2, que está preenchida com um texto digitado errado, em milhares de registros. Gostaria de fazer um `UPDATE` substituindo o texto errado pelo correto.

Answer (score 15):

É possível usar a função [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) do tsql, da seguinte forma em um comando UPDATE:

```
UPDATE nomeTabela
  SET colunaTexto = REPLACE ( colunaTexto , 'tetxo-erraddo' , 'texto-correto' )
```

Além do mais, se quiser fazer update somente nos registros necessários, use uma cláusula WHERE, filtrando os registros usando LIKE:

```
UPDATE nomeTabela
  SET colunaTexto = REPLACE ( colunaTexto , 'tetxo-erraddo' , 'texto-correto' )
  WHERE colunaTexto LIKE '%tetxo-erraddo%'
```

Referência: [Using REPLACE in an UPDATE statement](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement)

Comment: complementando, se o campo for do tipo TEXT ou NTEXT não vai funcionar, tem que fazer cast do tipo:
UPDATE [CMS_DB_test].[dbo].[cms_HtmlText] 
SET Content = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Content as NVarchar(4000)),'ABC','DEF') AS NText)

Answer (score 6):

A resposta de Miguel Angelo parece-me correcta. Só gostaria de acrescentar que, antes de você se lançar num Update, faça os Selects que forem necessários para afinar a sua condição Where, até ter a certeza que o seu filtro está a seleccionar exactamente os registos que procura, nem mais nem menos. Algo do estilo:

```
SELECT colunaTexto 
FROM nomeTabela 
WHERE colunaTexto LIKE '%texto_errado%'
```

Comment: E boa sorte para verificar os milhares de registros.

Comment: estava buscando exatamente isso. Facilitou demais encontrar email com vírgula.

Answer (score 6):

Acho interessante realizar updates, por mais simples que sejam, da seguinte forma:

```cs
update t
set nomeColuna = replace(nomeColuna, 'xx', 'yy')
--select * --select pode ser executado e trará os mesmos registros que o update atualizará
from nomeTabela as t
where t.nomeColuna like '%texto_procurado%'
```

Este tipo de update evita em muitos casos, que se faça o famoso update sem where, porque ao executar somente as duas primeiras linhas dá erro de execução porque não existe tabela com nome "t" no banco de dados (alias usado somente em tempo de execução).

Answer (score 2):

nomeu caso quero apenas corrigir o cadastro para emissao de NFe, entao tenho que trocar vogais acentuadas, ç, ", etc ...

Estou usando:

```
UPDATE TABELA CAMPO = REPLACE(CAMPO, 'º', 'o')
```

Abs